# Playing music using python

Tags: python, audio-player

I have a small piece of coding that I would like to use to play either mp3 files or wave files. Im not sure how to do this.

By the way I am fairly new to programming and am using python 3.2.

All help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It depends on your platform. Windows, Mac, Android, iOS, Linux?

Comment: I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You could use http://www.pygame.org/news.html

Then something like this using [pygame.mixer.music](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html):

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("myfile.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```